# Start windows service automatically for a dotnet service

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I need to run following commands every time server is started.

```
cd Desktop\Entitlement\Service
dotnet run --urls http://0.0.0.0:80
```

I think the solution is based on PowerShell and then installing as a Service.

I need guidance on the right direction and a solution. Thanks

Comment: [.NET apps can be packaged as Windows Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service)

Comment: Thanks, but I have to write some code for that, is there a PowerShell or Command Prompt based solution?

Comment: If the application doesn't have any way to communicate with the Windows Service manager, it's not possible to run it as a windows service. You can set the application to auto-launch at login using Task Scheduler, and might be able to look into launching it at startup the same way. If you're intent on using PowerShell to register a windows service, look into the `New-Service` cmdlet once you've modified your executable to support it.